# Post-install errors while installing pywin32-216 on Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, installation, pywin32

I'm using the `pywin32-216.win32-py2.6.exe` package to install pywin32 on `Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`. I am seeing the following post install errors. Could someone help me understand what going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
Copied pythoncom26.dll to C:\WINDOWS\system32\pythoncom26.dll
Copied pythoncomloader26.dll to C:\WINDOWS\system32\pythoncomloader26.dll
Copied pywintypes26.dll to C:\WINDOWS\system32\pywintypes26.dll
FAILED to register the Python COM objects
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\2.6\Help[None]=None
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\2.6\Help\Pythonwin Reference[None]='C:\\Python26\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyWin32.chm'
Failed to register pythonwin as editor
Shortcut for Pythonwin created
Shortcut to documentation created
The pywin32 extensions were successfully installed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 372, in install
  File "<string>", line 170, in RegisterCOMObjects
ImportError: No module named server.register
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 401, in install
  File "<string>", line 226, in RegisterPythonwin
  File "win32com\shell\shell.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "win32com\shell\shell.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by eventually cleaning all traces of Python 2.6 from my system and re-installing it + pywin32. It was eventually as simple as just double clicking the setup files.

Comment: could you please provide us the link?!

Comment: @Radu Which link would like me to provide? Link to the solution or link to the setup files? There is no link to the solution, I figured it out myself. Links to the setup files can be easily obtained using Google

Comment: I totally disagree, the setup files cannot be found easily. I found them - but not easily.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably pywin32 requires administrator privileges to be installed successfully. I am not sure how to do that on WinXP, but Microsoft has a [page](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_security_runas.mspx?mfr=true) about it.

Comment: My user is part of the Administrators group, shouldn't that be enough or do I need to run it as the actual 'Administrator' user.

Comment: That wouldn't be enough, you need to explicitly run it as an adminstrator.

Comment: Hi, I managed to get around this by removing my existing Python 2.6 installation and trying it again. It worked this time, hence I guess in this case, the privileges that I had were enough. Thanks a lot for looking into it. I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. On Vista I had a similar problem for a couple of times which I eliminated by running the setup exe as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer for the googlers:

I has the same issue, it turns out it originated because I have installed python in the past, removed it and reinstalled it to another location.
In order to solve it I had to:

1. Remove old installations (Uninstall + manually from registry) - as Danish advised (both in main root and in **Wow6432Node**).
2. In the registry update the location of current location of the python folder path (in **InstallPath** and **PythonPath**).