# error on installing pywin32 for python 2.6 on winXP

Tags: python, pywin32

I get the following error at the end of installing pywin32-216.win32-py2.6.exe for python-2.6.msi for WinXP.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 604, in <module>
 File "<string>", line 314, in install
 File "<string>", line 152, in LoadSystemModule
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Screenshot: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/mvQziLhUnX8DN8otUhaJSg?feat=directlink

I tried the advice in [Post-install errors while installing pywin32-216 on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611102/post-install-errors-while-installing-pywin32-216-on-windows-xp) and it did not work.  How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio suggested 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731786/pycairo-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found/4731796#4731796) you should run 
[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to understand what's amiss.